# what is the best way to get values of a variable through out function line-by-line?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL function.
In that function, there is a variable that changes its value.
I want to take that behavior of value of the variable.
So I want to get the value of that variable line by line.
what is the best way to do this? Or is there any function that I can call?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you post an example or pseudocode which explains the problem?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please, provide the code of the function and describe what exactly you're looking for.

Comment: Are you talking about debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want your function to output multiple outputs which are the different states of your variable during the running of the function.

I dont think there is really any way to do that since functions only have a single output. You could separate the function into a bunch of functions for each step and run them one after the other. Or you could do a procedure with multiple out values, and then at each step when you want to get the value of your variable, you assign the value to one of your out parameters.

Comment: i know i can get the value of variable by using dbms_output.put_line() on the lines and take the values,  But i want to know is is there a better /easier way ?

Comment: There is, for example - you could return a refcursor or a table. That depends on what you really are doing, but - for some reason - you chose not to share that information with us, although you've been asked to do that twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very ... sparse :-) but perhaps you are referring to something like a pipelined function, which can output data as it executes that can then be consumed via SQL. Example below:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2  function my_func return sys.odcinumberlist pipelined as
  3    my_var int := 0;
  4  begin
  5    pipe row ( my_var);
  6    my_var := my_var + 10;
  7    pipe row ( my_var);
  8    my_var := my_var * 10;
  9    pipe row ( my_var);
 10    return;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from my_func();

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           0
          10
         100
```

but as others have said, we're just guessing here.